# Loading spinner issue

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
            <div id="grid" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this code, the `#grid` element populates a chart but what I need is a loading spinner which indicates that chart is loading and it must be hidden once the chart populates.

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this?

Comment: Where is your async code that's loading the chart?

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm correct in understanding your question you would need something like:

```
$(function (){
   var grid = $("#grid");

   grid.html("<img src='ajax-img' />");

   $.post("/url", function(data){
       if(data != ""){
            grid.html(data);
       }
   });     
});
```

this function would run on document ready since you didn't specify when it should be triggered.